# What is the correct .tpl file to edit the footer links in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I need to edit the footer links in my Prestashop template ( just to add a  wrapper). That's the link list that comes afterthe block-contact. This is the block that shows links to special offers, product categories, best sales...and then comes another block of links related to CMS pages.

Do you know which files i have to edit?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i got it, for anyone who had the same issue, here's the correct .tpl :

modules\ps_linklist\views\templates\hook\linkblock.tpl